# Issue with EditText's On TextChange Listener

Tags: android, kotlin

In my Recyclerview's Adapter class, I have done something as below:

```
holder.mEdtDescription.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        listener.onDeleteOrDescribe(position, "" + holder.mEdtDescription.text.toString(), "describe")
    }
})

holder.mIvDelete.setOnClickListener {
    listener.onDeleteOrDescribe(position, "", "delete")
}
```

`mEdtDescription` is EditText.

On deleting some value from the recycler my adapter calls method `onDeleteOrDescribe`. 
Unfortunately, At the same time onTextChanged is also calling.

How can I avoid calling `onTextChanged` when I am deleting soemthing?

Hope you got the point.

As per the solution, I have tried disabling textWatcher as below :

```
val textWatcher: TextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            ToastUtil.displayShortDurationToast(mContext,"called")
            listener.onDeleteOrDescribe(
                position,
                "" + holder.mEdtDescription.text.toString(),
                "describe"
            )
        }
    }
    holder.mEdtDescription.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)

    holder.mIvDelete.setOnClickListener {
        //listener.onDeleteStep(position)
        holder.mEdtDescription.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        listener.onDeleteOrDescribe(position, "", "delete")
        holder.mEdtDescription.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
    }
```

But, still is calling onTextChange()   :(

Answer (score 1):

You could try disabling the TextWatcher temporarily:

```
val textWatcher :  TextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        listener.onDeleteOrDescribe(position, holder.mEdtDescription.text.toString(), "describe")
    }
}

holder.mEdtDescription.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)

holder.mIvDelete.setOnClickListener {
    holder.mEdtDescription.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
    listener.onDeleteOrDescribe(position, "", "delete")
    holder.mEdtDescription.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
}
```

Comment: But, it should called when I change editext content, in this case this will not work when I will change description.

Comment: it also not worked. I have disabled and enabled it inside

Comment: So, when mIvDelete onClickListener is triggered the onTextChanged() method is called? Even if the TextChangedListener is previously removed?

Comment: Yes sir, I have checked it by making toast inside.